# How to send data wirelessly from Raspberry pi to another network at remote place?

Tags: pi-3b+, web-server, pi-4

I have to live stream video feed captured from rpi to the remotely placed device which is connected to another network. Please help me finding any link or any stack exchange post.

My rpi is connected to a 3G cellular module and I have also created wifi through the cellular module just like hotspot and through this I want to send live feed videos to a remote network with 3g cellular module.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add more info before you get any good answers.

For example, is the pi currently connected to any type of network?

If it is, it should be straightforward to access a video feed its producing. (check out [dataplicity](https://docs.dataplicity.com) ).

If it's not, then you'll have to create a network for it to connect to, which is a different type of problem (buy a wifi router and connect it to the internet, buy a 3G cellular module, etc).

If you fill in more info about the situation, more people are likely to chime in. This has been done before so you just need to break down your tasks and focus on what you actually need to happen first.

Good luck.

Comment: My rpi is connected to 3G cellular module and I have also created wifi through the cellular module just like hotspot and through this I want to send live feed videos to a remote network with 3g cellular module. Thank you